# SQLITE PreparedStatement always return empty ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

I am wondering why this method always empty ResultSet:

```
    public boolean checkIfUsersExists(String email) throws SQLException {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email= ?;";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, email);

    log.info(preparedStatement.toString());

    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    return resultSet.next();
}
```

This method works good:

```
    public boolean checkIfUsersExists(String email) throws SQLException {
    String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='%s';", email);
    log.info(query);
    ResultSet resultSet = getConnection()
            .createStatement()
            .executeQuery(query);

    return resultSet.next();
}
```

I need to use PreparedStatement to avoid SQL injection, but it does not work in this case.
I use sqlite 3.21.0.1

Comment: its working fine in my machine.. can you please show your imported classes for PreparedStatement and ResultSet

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY Does it matter that i have autoCommit set to True ?

Comment: just try with false, may be not :P

Comment: log.info(preparedStatement.toString()); what this line is prints, and one more thing please pass email hard coded in this line preparedStatement.setString(1, email);

Comment: Just to clarify: What exact value does `resultSet.next()` return?